# Using function inside PHP Namespace

Tags: php, function, namespaces

I'm playing with a CMS that utilizes Namespaces and I'm trying to make use of it instead of including files and using functions within those files.

From what I understand and have tried, I have a file loaded as a PSR-4 with a declared namespace, class, and a function inside that I'd like to access. It looks like:

```
namespace MyFunctions;

    class basic {

        function say_hello($a) { 
            echo "Hello, $a"; 
        }

    }
```

And from another file, I can see that the "MyFunctions" namespace is indeed loaded when checking using the **get_declared_classes()** function. However, I'm completely lost with how to use the "say_hello()" function.

I've tried:

```
use MyFunctions;

// instantiate class
$a = new basic();

// this gives me 'call to undefined function'
echo say_hello("Bob");
```

I've tried digging at other examples and I'm chomping at the bits trying to access this function. Could someone give me an example of how I would get to, and use, the "say_hello()" function from another file? Any help would be HUGELY appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Even though a class is namespaced, you still need to instantiate it before accessing its methods`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the setup you have here. You would have to execute the following to fire that function.

```
(new MyFunctions\basic)->say_hello("Bob");
```

(I dont recommend this method, it creates an object for no reason.)

What I'm assuming you wanted was:

```
namespace MyFunctions;

function say_hello($a)
{
    echo "Hello, $a";
}
```

at which point you could use

```
// this gives you 'Hello, Bob'
MyFunctions\say_hello("Bob");
```

Comment: The latter example was exactly what I needed! I guess I was largely confused by the Class itself which I didn't need.